# Start Firefox in Safe Mode Automatically

Tags: firefox, startup-applications

How can I open Firefox (version `79.0`, 64-bit) in Safe Mode automatically using StartUp Applications in Ubuntu `18.04.5` LTS?

Answer (score 1):

For each custom startup application, you will find a `.desktop` launcher in the folder `~./config/autostart`. `.config` is a hidden folder. Enable "Show hidden Files" to see it in the file manager.

- In that folder, locate the file for Firefox and open it in a text editor.
- Find a line starting with `Exec=`, that specifies the command needed to run firefox. Add the command line options you need to have Firefox launch in Safe Mode, as in

  `Exec=firefox -safe-mode %u`

See `man firefox` for the manual detailing the syntax of the `firefox` command and its options.

Comment: Where is my '~./config/autostart' folder?  I am a newbie ;)

Comment: It is a "hidden" folder. See my updated answer.